# How to empty INPUT after checking for numeric value?

Tags: html, input, jscript

I would like to check if the INPUT value is a number, and if not, the field should be     cleared. The script below always gives the alert if it's not numeric, but never cleares the input. Anyone an idea what I did wrong?

```
<script>
   function numeric(input)
   {
      if(isNaN(input))
      {
          alert("Is not a numeric value");
          input.value="";
      }
   }
</script>

<input type="number" value="" name="<?php echo $x; ?>" onblur="return numeric(value)"/>
```

Comment: Small mistake. Taken lazyness as key factor why mistakes happen (not a joke at all), I rate this question as a typo, just a small oversight proof-reading the code in question (see non-jQuery answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$( "#numerictext" ).keyup(function() {

var numberRegex = /^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/;
var str = $('#numerictext').val();

if(!numberRegex.test(str)) {
   alert("Is not a numeric value");
   $('#numerictext').val('')
}

});

    <input type="number" id="numerictext" value="" name="<?php echo $x; ?>"/>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wanted straight javascript (no jQuery)

Comment: @MattEno if have given negative then let me tell you this answer is not wrong and let him decide what to choose

Comment: Nice answer and yes let op decide what to choose :)

Comment: @Nicolas123 If you got the answer mark as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the value into your function, then trying to clear the input by refering to its value.  Instead, try:

```
<script>
   function numeric(input)
   {
      if(isNaN(input.value))
      {
          alert("Is not a numeric value");
          input.value="";
      }
   }
</script>

<input type="number" value="" name="<?php echo $x; ?>" onblur="return numeric(this)"/>
```